# Android Studio 2.2 Gridlayout not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, tooltip, android-relativelayout

I can understand maybe Android Studio 2.2 is different but I feel like it's not working at all with GridLayout, I'm watching thenewboston tutorial 17 for GridLayout, and when he makes it wrap around content then drag the buttons into it, it shows a bit of information over the mouse about where the button is going to be placed (Then shows green bars to indicate where the button is), mine doesn't do that and also it doesn't work at all. I'll include a gif of what I'm talking about.

Also, how do you enable the tooltips for the palette? and no I'm not talking about the quick docs but the mouse hover tip over the palette items.

Here is a gif https://gyazo.com/8a2bc1919f3d117238b7f52be11a2316
And also the error codes that pop up, one of them says view requires API Level 14 (Current min 9):<.GridLayout/>

And the other says

This Gridlayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding dropping the button on the Grid... just drop the button on the GridLayout on the component tree (bottom left). Once you have the first item there you can use the grid as you'd normally expect it to work by moving the buttons around.

[image: Example]

Comment: Link leading to not found page.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is a tad old, but also that it comes up quickly in a google search, so I hope that my solution can be of help to some one.

I was going through this same tutorial, and while I was never able to figure out if it's possible to enable the green lines or drag and drop properly into a GridLayout, I did find how to do it explicitly in the XML file.

In the tag for your button, simply add:

```
android:layout_row="X"
android:layout_column="X"
```

where x is any (positive) integer number from top to bottom for the row value, and left to right for the column value.

A less than ideal solution I know, but hopefully some one will benefit from this.